# laravel - how to check auth guard in javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, authentication

in balde and controller when i want to get the authenticated admin i use

`$data=Auth::guard('admin')->user();`

is there a way to get this in a javascript variable and then console.log it?

i have tried to solve this by this but it doesn't work. I have also searched google and stackoverflow but cannot get an existing answer

```
var data = <?php Auth::guard('admin')->user();?>
console.log(data);
```

i'm using hesto multiauth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem by doing this.

`var data =  <?= Auth::guard('customer')->user() ?>;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your blade file:

```
<script>
   var data = {!! Auth::guard('admin')->user() !!}
   console.log(data);
</script>
```

Comment: this is not working. the following error is displayed on the console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &.